# Calling ExecutorService submit() inside an infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

My question is regarding the `shutdown()` method from the ExecutorService class. If i am calling the `submit()` method in an infinite loop... do i ever need to call `shutdown()`? Essentially i have something like this (pseudo-code here):

```
for(;;){
    for(some event){

     if(some event does something i want to capture){
        threadPool.submit()     
     }
    }
}
```

So with a set up like the above when is it appropriate to call `shutdown()` ? In my actual code when i try to call shutdown() outside the infinite loop i get unreachable code error - which i understand. But it seems to me that i would probably not call the `shutdown()` method. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest passing a *stop* event type that instructs the loop to `break`:

```
boolean have_received_stop_event = false;
while (!have_received_stop_event)
{
    for(some event)
    {
        if(stop-event)
        {
            have_received_stop_event = true;
            break;
        }

        if(some event does something i want to capture)
        {
            threadPool.submit()     
        }
    }
}
```

Then call `shutdown()` after main loop exits.

Comment: maybe make the boolean volatile, if it's to be set from a different thread?

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths, but it is not set from a different thread. It is set when this thread receives a stop event.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a try-catch block enclosing this infinite loop, you could call shutdown in the catch block.  This would allow you to tidy up when an exception is thrown.